# Combine multiple column into two column in r

Tags: r

The dataset originally looked like this, it has 50 columns, the first is the username, the second is X, then X.1, up to the column "X.48".
[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mPpF.png)

I only need the result of a dataset with two columns namely username and X . The X is a row containing all columns X.1 to X.48. So, I first delete the empty row for column X and join the username and column X together.

```
df3 = df2[!(is.na(df2$X) | df2$X==""),]
df_final = subset(df3,select = c(username,X))
```

[Dataset Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVqQ5.png)

After that delete the empty row for column X.1, then stack at the bottom of username and X.

```
df_loop = subset(df3,select = -c(X))
df_loop1 = df_loop[!(is.na(df_loop$X.1) | df_loop$X.1==""),]
df_final1 = subset(df_loop1,select = c(username,X.1))

colnames(df_final1) <- colnames(df_final)
combine_data = rbind(df_final,df_final1)
```

Then the dataset will end up being just two columns. But now the problem is, without the for loop, it takes a lot of time to complete this task. I tried using a for loop to loop this task but failed, can anyone help?

dataset : https://gofile.io/d/LpmpH8

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Have a look at `tidyr::unite()`.  Something like, `df_final1 <- tidyr::unite(df_final, "X", !"username")`

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are attempting to do. Could you give an example of what you want the end result to look like, and what problem you are having?